# Daemonize 'child_process' that was 'fork'ed

Tags: linux, node.js, apache, daemon, child-process

I am trying to achieve a behavior similar to one that `httpd` has when starting with NodeJS. When we say:

```
service httpd start
```

In `ps`, we'll see:

```
[root@dev ~]# service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@dev ~]# ps auxf | grep httpd
root      3395  0.0  0.1   6336   304 pts/0    R+   12:03   0:00  |       \_ grep httpd
root      3391  0.0  1.3 175216  3656 ?        Ss   12:02   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    3393  0.0  0.9 175216  2432 ?        S    12:02   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
```

Notice how `httpd` master and child have no terminal (`?` is shown instead of `pts/0` for `grep`).

Now... I need an IPC channel and therefore I use [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) but no matter what I do, every time I see a terminal still attached to my daemon. Here is the code you are welcome to experiment on:

`c.js` - controller

```
var cp = require('child_process');

var d = cp.fork('d.js', {});

d.on('message', function() {
  d.disconnect();
  d.unref();
});
```

`d.js` - daemon

```
process.send('ready');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('test');
}, 10000);
```

And this is what I see in terminal:

```
[root@dev ~]# node c.js                 # running the control script
[root@dev ~]# ps auxf | grep node       # my terminal is interactive again so I check
root      3472  0.0  0.3 103308   864 pts/0    S+   12:13   0:00  |       \_ grep node
root      3466  1.1  5.6 648548 14904 pts/0    Sl   12:13   0:00 /usr/bin/node d.js
[root@dev ~]# test                      # appears outta nowhere because d.js still has this stdout
```

`d.js` still has my `pts/0` and writes `test` to it even when it's already interactive with `bash` for me.

**How do I fix that and make daemon drop the terminal?** I don't care which side (`c.js` or `d.js`) gets adjustments to code, I control both, but I need that **IPC channel** and therefore this has to be done via `fork`.

Comment: Relevant [issue](https://github.com/odin-public/aps-node-runtime/issues/7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by ditching `fork` in favor of `spawn`. Same code can then be rewritten to:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var d = cp.spawn(process.execPath, ['./d.js'], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore', 'ipc']
});

d.unref();
d.disconnect();
```

The `stdio` part is how `fork` works internally. I have no idea why they decided to not expose the full array and instead gave only `silent`.

`d.js` will then have no terminal right at the start (it will be `/dev/null` - same as `httpd`). Not tested on Windows.